# SDL2 Renderer not drawing anything to screen

Tags: c++, sdl-2, game-development

I'm trying to make my first game using C++ with SDL2. For now I'm just trying to get the screen to show up properly. When I run my code a window appears but instead of a blue background the window just shows up in plain white as if the renderer isn't doing anything. Here is my code:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

//Screen dimension constants
const int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 800;
const int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 600;

bool initWindow(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer) {
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Pong", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << "Window could not be created! SDL_Error:\n" << SDL_GetError();
        return false;
    }
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (renderer == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Window could not be created! SDL_Error:\n" << SDL_GetError();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

void pollEvents(bool &gameOver) {
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            gameOver = true;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym) {
            case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                gameOver = true;
                break;
            case SDLK_w:
                std::cout << "Test";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    bool gameOver = false;
    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error:\n" << SDL_GetError();
    }
    else
    {
        if (initWindow(window, renderer)) {
            while (!gameOver) {
                // Draw everything
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 200, 255);
                SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

                pollEvents(gameOver);
            }
        }
    }
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of just dumping your code, you could help out others help you by mentioning details such as what you did, what problems you faced, or what error messages you've seen.  If you don't help others help you, you'll hardly get any help.

Answer (score 2):

**Copies** of what are specified are passed to the arguments of the function

```
bool initWindow(SDL_Window* window, SDL_Renderer* renderer)
```

and modification to them won't affect what are passed.

You should add `&` to the arguments and make them references to have the assignments affect the local variables of `main()`.

```
bool initWindow(SDL_Window*& window, SDL_Renderer*& renderer)
```